# If the number of positive integer $n$ for which $n \leq 1991$ and $6$ is a factor of $n^2 + 3n + 2$ is given by $K$, Find the value of $\sqrt{K - 32}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I tried by factorising $n^2 + 3n + 2$ into $(n + 1)(n + 2)$ and tried by
assuming $ n = 2k + 1 $ and $ n = 2k $ for odd and even respectively and puting them in place of n

For odd : $(2k + 2)(2k+ 3)$ $\Rightarrow$ $2k + 3$ should be divisible by 3

For even :
$(2k + 1)(2k + 2)$ $\Rightarrow$ $2k + 1$ should be divisible by 3

But I can't proceed any further... Can anyone explain how to go through this question?

Comment: @AlbusDumbledore I have edited the question... we have to find "the number of positive integer n" which satisfies the above condition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $f(n)=(n+1)(n+2)$. Each six consecutive integers from $n=1$ till $n=1991$ contains two numbers $f(n)$ which have not $6$ as a factor and these are $$3,6,9,12,\cdots,1989$$ They formed an evident arithmetic progression so there are $1989:3=663$ numbers involved that are not multiples of $6$. It follows that one has $1991-663=1328$ numbers having $6$ as a factor.

Thus $K=1328$ and the asked number is then $\sqrt{1296}=36$.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: for positive integer $n$, $(n+1)(n+2)$ is divisible by $6$ if and only if $n$ is not divisible by $3$.

This is because $(n+1)(n+2)$ is even, and if $n$ is not divisible by $3$, one of $ n+1, n+2$ would be. If $n$ is divisible by $3$, the situation reverses.

Answer (score 0):

Observe that:

$$(n+6)^2 + 3(n+6) + 2 = n^2+12n+36+3n+18+2 = (n^2+3n+2) + 12n+36+18$$
$$ = (n^2+3n+2) + 6(2n+6+3).$$

Therefore, if $n^2+3n+2$ is divisible by $6$, then $(n+6)^2 + 3(n+6) + 2$ is as well. If $n^2+3n+6$ is not divisible by $6$, $(n+6)^2 + 3(n+6) + 2$ is also not divisible by $6$.

Find which $n$ where $1 ≤ n ≤ 6$ the statement is true for. Then, since all natural numbers have remainders from $1$ to $6$ ($0$) when divided by $6$, you can extend this to all natural numbers.